# How to stop selenium to download chromedriver everytime

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm always using the following code to initiate my selenium web driver. But the problem is, it always tries to download the latest chrome driver. How can I prevent this behavior and just let it update if there is any update on the real chrome browser?

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(cache_valid_range=0).install()), options=options)
```

UPDATE:
I think my first problem was that `cache_valid_range` is set to zero and because of that it always tries to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

you can download chromedriver for your os and right version from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
and pass the absolute path to executable path below.

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =r"C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe", options=options)`

This will not download the driver again

Comment: Not worked, it just try to download again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use chromedriver-autoinstaller

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

After this code then add your code after

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```